# Heroku github organization integration

Tags: github, heroku, github-organizations, heroku-ci

How do I connect Heroku pipeline with a private repository in github-organization (on Github.com)

Currently, I can see only my private repositories, but I'd like to connect a private repository in our organization account.

Answer (score 1):

For org owned github repos you need to do the following:

- Ensure you have admin-level access to the repository
- Ensure you are the owner or member of the organization
- Visit https://github.com/settings/connections/applications/, click 'Heroku Dashboard' and then grant access to the org you wish to connnect to.